# Fourier Transform of $1$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was wondering, why is the Fourier Transform of $1$ equal to the Dirac Delta Function? I found derivations based on the inverse Fourier Transform, but can someone show the Fourier Transform integral converges to this specific function? Also is the Dirac Delta Function that is the result of this transform equal to $1$ or infinity at $0$? I ask because I've found conflicting results in literature.

Comment: You deal with distributions here, so you cannot think of the Fourier transform as an integral (the function $1$ is not $L^1$).

Comment: The Dirac delta function is not a function. We call it that because it behaves a lot like one and it was invented by physicist who play fast and loose with mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ is defined as

$$\mathcal{F}_t[f(t)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\,e^{-2 i \pi x t}\,dt\tag{1}$$

the Fourier transform of $f(t)=1$ is

$$\mathcal{F}_t[1](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2 i \pi x t}\,dt=\delta(x)\tag{2}$$

which leads to the limit representations

$$\delta(x)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\int_{-f}^f e^{-2 i \pi x t}\,dt\right)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2 f\, \text{sinc}(2 \pi f x)\right)\tag{3}$$

and

$$\theta(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \delta(y)\,dy=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\text{Si}(2 \pi f x)}{\pi}\right).\tag{4}$$

---

The following figure illustrates formula (3) for $\delta(x)$ above evaluated at $f=4$.

[image: Illustration of formula (3)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (3) for $\delta(x)$ evaluated at $f=4$

---

The Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ is sometimes left undefined at $x=0$ (Mathematica evaluates $\delta(x)$ to $0$ for real $x\ne 0$ but refuses to evaluate $\delta(0)$), but using formula (3) for $\delta(x)$ above leads to

$$\delta(0)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}(2 f\, \text{sinc}(2 \pi f\, 0))=\infty\,.\tag{5}$$

since $\text{sinc}(0)=1$.

---

The following figure illustrates formula (4) for $\theta(x)$ above evaluated at $f=4$.

[image: Illustration of formula (4)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (4) for $\theta(x)$ evaluated at $f=4$

---

Also note that using formula (3) for $\delta(x)$ above leads to

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2 f\, \text{sinc}(2 \pi f x)\,dx=1\tag{6}$$

---

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2580256) user [reuns](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/reuns) posted to one of my questions on Math StackExchange provides a more rigorous answer with respect to the Fourier transform of $1$.

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't believe there's anything incorrect in my answer above. Formula (3) is consistent with the limit representation $\underset{\epsilon\to0}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{\pi x}\sin\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)\right)$ (see formula (37) at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) using the variable substitution $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2 \pi  f}$.

Comment: I upvoted you to counter the downvote. I hate those sneaky downvotes with no explanation.

Comment: @StefanLafon Thanks. I think defining and illustrating limit representations of distributions helps to provide insight to those unfamiliar with generalized functions.