# Fourier transform of power series

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

Suppose I have a sequence $c_n$, and I make the formal power series $\phi(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nt^n$. I can take the (inverse) fourier transform of $\phi(t)$

$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}{e^{itx}\phi(t)dt}$.

I could then compute the integral to find $f_X(x)$ in terms of $c_n$, but doing so is proving to be beyond me. What I'm ultimately interested in is how the $d_m$ in the expansion $f_X(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}d_mt^m$ are related to the $c_n$ in the expansion of $\phi(t)$.

Comment: I believe the general result is $\mathcal{F}_t^{-1}\left[t^n\right](x)=(-i)^n\,\delta ^{(n)}(x)$ where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function which is a distribution (generalized function), but I don't understand what your ultimate goal is as the last sentence doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Are your trying to find a Fourier series for the power series of $\phi(t)$ or a power series for $\mathcal{F}_t^{-1}\left[\phi(t)\right](x)$?

Comment: I'm primarily trying to find the inverse Fourier transform for $\phi(t)$, which is a power series. The last sentence of my question is a secondary matter, but I'm hoping that there is some useful correspondence between the Maclaurin series coefficients of $f_X(x)$ and the coefficients of $\phi(t)$.

Comment: The inverse Fourier transform is an infinite series of distributions: $\mathcal{F}_t^{-1}\left[\phi(t)\right](x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n\,(-i)^n\,\delta ^{(n)}(x)$. It seems to me you could potentially find a Maclaurin series for each term (e.g. using a limit representation of $\delta(x)$), but you'd end up with an infinite series of Maclaurin series, so converting this to a single Maclaurin series would result in an infinite series representation of each coefficient.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. I hadn't realized that you would end up with an infinite series for each coefficient, but now that you spell it out it makes sense. Would you mind explaining where the $\delta(x)$ in the result comes from? When I tried to do the integral I arrived at $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{c_n\int t^n e^{-itx}dt}$, and couldn't see how to progress.

Comment: The answer user reuns posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2580256 to one of my questions provides an explanation with respect to the Fourier transform of $t^0=1$. The results for $t^n$ where $n\ne 0$ can perhaps be derived from this result and the relationships between the Fourier transforms of a function and it's derivative or integral,

Comment: You can experiment with different values of $n$ on Wolfram Alpha to see the pattern (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FourierTransform%5Bt%5E3%2Ct%2Cx%5D and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=InverseFourierTransform%5Bt%5E3%2Ct%2Cx%5D), but note Wolfram Alpha uses a slightly different definition of the Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms than what you're using resulting in a different scaling constant.