# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}\mathrm\;{dt}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, fourier-transform

> Evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}\mathrm\;{dt}$$

This is an integration from a textbook chapter discussing wave involving Fourier transform, which try to deal with dispersion. How to solve this integral? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hi. Community here prefers typing Mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that content is clear. Since you are new contributor, the typing has been done. (If you can't see updated text, assume that typing process is in Queue). It is advisable to get yourself trained with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that from future you can type your question self. If possible, we would like to see your efforts on question too. Happy Learning!

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to the page talking about MathJax. I will learn from it

Comment: Yes, now it's correct. Thanks for help

Comment: The integral doesn’t exist as written - the real part is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(\omega-\omega_0)t\,dt$$which doesn’t converge.

Comment: The integral cannot be solved in the classic sense. It is a divergent integral, which is easily checked. However this expression is often used informally for distributional identities, and if I remember correctly this integral “is” a formula “for” the Dirac delta. Strictly speaking though, it is nonsense: it must be interpreted in a certain sense

Comment: I stuck at this step when reading the textbook talking about wave. Yeah, after giving this integral, the auther introduce Dirac delta in the part considering dispersion without any explanation.

Comment: As I said, it is nonsense. But, with the right machinery, it can be interpreted well, as done [here](https://books.physics.oregonstate.edu/LinAlg/deltaexp.html). To be clear, they are **not** evaluating this integral - rather, they are using a *regularisation* method, which is a way of assigning "meaningful" values to otherwise divergent integrals or series (see for instance Cesaro or Abel summation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Classical_summation_methods))

Comment: @FShrike: Thanks for sharing the links! That's what I want. I will study the links carefully.

Comment: Assuming the Fourier transform is defined as $\mathcal{F}_t[f(t)](\omega )=\int\limits_{-\infty }^\infty f(t)\, e^{i \omega t}\,dt$, it's the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}_t\left[e^{-i \omega_0 t}\right](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\omega-\omega_0) t}\,{dt}=2 \pi \delta(\omega-\omega_0)$.

Comment: @StevenClark That presupposes a particular meaning for integrals over $\Bbb R$, in this case something like the limit as a measure, not as a pointwise function of $\omega$, as $\epsilon\to0^+$ of the [_nascent delta function_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function) $\eta_\epsilon(\omega):=\int_{-1/\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}e^{it\omega}dt$.

Comment: @J.G. The integral corresponds to the limit representation $\underset{T\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\int\limits_{-T}^T e^{i t (\omega-\omega_0)}\,dt=2 T \text{sinc}(T (\omega-\omega_0))=2 \pi \delta(\omega-\omega_0)\right)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2580256 for convergence in the sense of distributions.

Comment: That's the phrase I was looking for.