# Fourier Inversion formula.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The Fourier Inversion Formula is excellently proved in the following site(Theorem 1): https://candes.su.domains/teaching/math262/Lectures/Lecture02.pdf

At the end of the proof, it is written as follows:

$$
I_{\epsilon}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)g_{\epsilon}(t-u)du,
$$
where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_{\epsilon}(x)dx = 1$ and $g_{\epsilon}(x)$ concentrates aound the origin, i.e., $x = 0$ as $\epsilon \mapsto 0$.

### Q. Why $I_{\epsilon}(t) \mapsto f(t)$ as $\epsilon \mapsto 0$?

One reasoning is that $g_{\epsilon} \mapsto \delta$ as $\epsilon \mapsto 0$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac's delta function. However, I want to know an ``elementary'' but still rigorous proof of the above question.

Comment: Because $g_\varepsilon(x)\rightarrow\delta(x)$ and $I_\varepsilon\rightarrow f*\delta = f$ when $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$, since the Dirac delta is the identity element of the convolution product $*$.

Comment: @Abezhiko Let $T_\epsilon$ be the distribution associated to $g_\epsilon$. You claim that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}T_\epsilon=\delta$ and hence $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}f*g_\epsilon=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}f*T_\epsilon=f*\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}T_\epsilon=f*\delta=f$$right?

Comment: @Filippo That's the idea, yes.

Comment: @Abezhiko Thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: The convolution with $g_\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ forms an approximate identity. Also it is more convenient to use $$I_\varepsilon(t)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(t-u)g_\varepsilon(u)\,du$$

Comment: Thanks for kind teachings. Pierre

Comment: This answer to one of my questions might be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2580256

Comment: Try showing that

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |(f(u)-f(t))g_{\epsilon}(t-u)|du \to 0$

so that 

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)g_{\epsilon}(t-u)du \to \lim \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)g_{\epsilon}(t-u)du = f(t)$